# Positioning DIVs/ stretching containers?

Tags: html, css, position, height

is there anyway to set the position of a common div on the bottom of the page, without pushing it out of its container, without setting container's height and absolutely without setting its position to absolute?

I mean, i'd like to set a div(alpha) to the bottom of the page, but it's contained in another div(beta), and i was wondering if there's any way to push alpha down and make it reach the bottom allowing beta to continue containing him?

this is my situation

```
<div class="beta">
    <tons of divs></tons of divs>
    <div class="alpha"></div>
</div>
```

and this is what i would like to obtain http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNYVZE

BUT without setting:

- beta display to flex;
- beta height;

any help would be much appreciated >.<

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can set `margin-top: (whateveryoulike)vh` on your `.alpha` element
like here http://codepen.io/rokki_balboa/pen/rVJKJy, 
but the best practice would be set `position: relative;` on `.beta` and `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` on `.alpha`

.

Comment: might be worth finding out what is good practice before answering!